# How to get all download url from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, java, php, android

I'm a newbie and I am trying to get all download url from firebase storage and display it in a table or a list .

Comment: You need a url to all files in your firebase storage location?

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: I normally save the firebase storage URLs in the firebase database. You can then pull these with the [firebase sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). Also keep in mind that a "storage reference" is different from a "downloadUrl" - [firebase storage docs](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. i appreciate it . i will definitely try this one . @Jim

Comment: @kabuto178 . yes . I want that the moment I upload files to the firebase storage, the download url will be displayed in my firebase database.

Comment: @JohnDown. I want to get all download urls in my firebase storage and display it in my firebase database .

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. Much Appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

The download URL isn't provided in the `snapshot` you receive when your file is uploaded to Storage. It'd be nice if Firebase provided this.

To get the download URL you use the method `getDownloadURL()` on your file's storage reference. There are two types of storage references, `firebase.storage.ref()` and `firebase.storage.refFromURL(`. The former uses the path to the file, which is provided in the `snapshot` after your file is uploaded to Storage. The latter uses either a Google Cloud Storage URI or a HTTPS URL, neither of which is provided in the `snapshot`. If you want to get the download URL immediately after uploading a file, you'll want to use `firebase.storage.ref()` and the file's path, e.g.,

```
firebase.storage.ref('English_Videos/Walker_Climbs_a_Tree/Walker_Climbs_a_Tree_3.mp4');
```

Here's the full code for uploading a file to Storage and getting the download URL:

```
firebase.storage().ref($scope.languageVideos + "/" + $scope.movieOrTvShow + "/" + $scope.videoSource.name).put($scope.videoSource, metadata) // upload to Firebase Storage
.then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Uploaded file to Storage.");
  firebase.storage().ref(snapshot.ref.location.path).getDownloadURL()   // get downloadURL
  .then(function(url) {
    var $scope.downloadURL = url;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: How in gods name does firebase not return the URL. There are thousands of SO questions asking for this because it's maybe the most basic need when it comes to media storage. Cloudinary does this. S3 does this.