# How to get the download URL from Firebase Storage used on Server Side

Tags: android, url, server, firebase-storage

The FireBase Storage for the download URL link is working perfectly on client side but I don't know how to retrieve it on my server, the signed URL is not working for me. Anyone knows more ways to archive this?

Comment: on serve side how you are retrieving

Comment: I'm doing it like the answer of @James Daniels on the first answer of this Thread. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase