# How do I access Firebase storage from within a Database-triggered Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I would like to perform file manipulation using firebase cloud functions by listening to an event triggered by `functions.database.ref().onWrite()` (instead of `functions.storage.object().onChange()`).

I noticed most of the sample using cloud functions `functions.storage.object().onChange()` to trigger a cloud functions for file manipulation. Is there a way to get a `storageRef` from within `functions.database.ref()` and perform file manipulation from there?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access Firebase Storage from within your database triggered Cloud Function, you can use the Google Cloud SDK.

From one of my apps:

```js
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

...
exports
.emojifyStory = functions.database.ref('/stories/{storyId}')
.onWrite(function(event) {
    const filePath = event.data.val().filePath;
    const file = gcs.bucket(bucket).file(filePath);

    // Use the Vision API to detect labels
    return visionClient.detectLabels(file)
      .then(data => {
      ...
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffeken I underderstand the part using Google Cloud SDK, just couldn't figure out how the get the `bucket` from Cloud Function. It is obvious to me now `bucket` is just `bucket = functions.config().firebase.storageBucket`. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffeken
I am using this way of getting a file, but I can't figure out how to fetch the file metadata from this object. Thanks in advance