# Xamarin.Android: Get Firebase Storage Download URL

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-storage

I have an UploadTask to send an image to Firebase Storage and it works but now I want to get the respective download URL but I'm facing some issues.

```
var upload = childRef.DownloadURL;

upload.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
```

I'm implementing the IOnSuccessListener interface so the function has to be:

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result){
   //get url from result
}
```

How can I cast the result to access the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)?

Comment: It's the same ideia but with Javascript. I'm using Xamarin.Android and things are a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution in debugging mode

i saw the downloadurl's properties and found the Scheme and SchemeSpecificPart

> Scheme = "https"
>
> SchemeSpecificPart = "//firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/maplog-e4ba5.appspot.com/o/-L0AMbihF23YKxsL1uss?alt=media&token=5c7ccef1-c857-4982-a288-fded2f0ff1aa"

so here is my code:

```
void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var snapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;
    string imgUrl = snapShot.DownloadUrl.Scheme 
    + ":" 
    + snapShot.DownloadUrl.SchemeSpecificPart;
}
```

and it works!
i was looking for the solution :((
but i finally found it myself XD

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, but was able to catch the error when adding the `AddOnFailureListener`. The error message wasn't helpful.

> An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner
>   exception for server response.

The result code was 0. The error code as -13000, which is an unknown error according to Firebase error table.

```
   FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
   FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.Instance;
   StorageReference storageRef = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://");
   StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.Child("folder/image.jpg");

   var downloadURL = imageRef.DownloadUrl.AddOnSuccessListener(this, this).AddOnFailureListener(this, this);

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {

        string downloadURL = result.ToString();
    }
    public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
    {
        Log.Warn("FirebaseStorage", "Download Failure", e);
    }
```

Comment: "string downloadURL = ((UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result).DownloadUrl.ToString()" is the answer!

Comment: Sorry Rafael. This did not solve the issue. The DownloadURL call still lands int the OnFailure with 13000 error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of the error code as -13000 which is an unknown error according to Firebase error table , i resolved by updating the playstore app in the device

Answer (score 0):

I would say    EncodedSchemeSpecificPart worked perfect for me

```
        var snapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;
        string downloadURL =snapShot.DownloadUrl.Scheme + ":" +snapShot.DownloadUrl.EncodedSchemeSpecificPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Xamarin Android this is the correct answer

```
public async void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var snapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;

    if (snapShot != null)
    {
        var url = await snapShot.Storage.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        imageUrl = url?.ToString();
    }
}
```