# Firebase web: Storage Location from Download URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm writing a firebase function where i need storage location.
Right now i have download url:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dxxxxxxxxx.com/o/videosvideo%3A67423?alt=media&token=acxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Is there a way to get Storage location like this:

[gs://dexxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/videosvideo:67423](http://gs://dekhoapp.appspot.com/videosvideo:67423)

from the given download url?

Comment: When you say "Firebase function", do you mean you're writing backend code with Cloud Functions for Firebase?  Or are you writing client side code?  Are you just trying to convert a https download URL to a gs URL?

Comment: Yes, i'm writing backend code with Cloud Functions for Firebase. And yes i want to convert a https download URL to a gs URL.

Comment: Is there a way? @Doug Stevenson

Comment: Is something wrong with [refFromUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#refFromURL)? Seems like what you're looking for. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 3):

The description for [refFromURl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#refFromURL) says that it returns a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) and accepts:

```
A URL in the form: 
1) a gs:// URL, for example gs://bucket/files/image.png 
2) a download URL taken from object metadata.
```

Based on this, I'd expect the following to work fine:

```
const downloadUrl = "https://firestorage.googleapis...";
const gsUrl = firebase.storage().refFromUrl(downloadUrl).toString();
```

Comment: Whenever i use firebase.storage() i get error firebase.storage is not a function. I know i have to use google cloud storage, but for that too i get gcs.ref is not a function. Anyway i needed bucket and filepath only from gs url which i manipulated from http url itself. Thanks though for your feedback.

Comment: Hello Kato, would you know the answer to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758262/how-to-implement-steam-auth-with-firebase