# Using Firebase Auth with Custom providers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase in a side project that requires authentication using Facebook, Twitter, Google and Twitch. Unfortunately, Firebase Auth doesn't support authentication using Twitch out of the box. I would like to know the best approach to solve the problem: can I use Firebase Auth & a Custom Auth system only for Twitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase supports signing in with any provider, as long as you are willing to write the code for it. The process is pretty well documented in a page called [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

If you're looking for samples for other providers, have a look at the [`functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples), which contains a.o. samples for signing in with LinkedIn, Okta, and Spotify.