# How can I reference a GCP cloud storage object, from the firebase download link, using the Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

My question is similar to this: [Firebase web: Storage Location from Download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530296/firebase-web-storage-location-from-download-url)

> I'm writing a firebase function where i need storage location. Right now i have download url:
>
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dxxxxxxxxx.com/o/videosvideo%3A67423?alt=media&token=acxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Is there a way to get Storage location like this:
>
> gs://dexxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/videosvideo:67423

The answer given is to do:

```
const downloadUrl = "https://firestorage.googleapis...";
const gsUrl = firebase.storage().refFromUrl(downloadUrl).toString();
```

However, the context I'm doing this, is as a Firebase Function - so I need to use the Admin SDK.

The [Admin SDK Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage) directly references the the [GCP Storage Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/), which don't have `refFromUrl()`.

Is there a simple way to do this? The context is - I want to delete the object for the given download link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a server side API that's going to do what you want.  I'd recommend storing not just the download URL in your database, but also the path to the file in storage.  That way, the server can deal with the file easily through the Admin SDK.

Comment: Yes - that is a solution I've considered.