# getDownloadURL for Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I am listening on changes to my images with Firebase to create a thumbnail. So on the serverside I download the image, resize the image and upload the thumbnail to my bucket:

```
defaultBucket.upload(tempFilePath)
```

Is there a way to get the download-URL for the file, I just uploaded?

I need something like [getSignedUrl](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.2.0/storage/file?method=getSignedUrl), just without expiration.
On the clientside I can use [getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL), but this does not work on the server.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Oh wow. I did really use the search function but didn't find anything. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)