# Unable to sign JWT when using serviceAccountId

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, jwt

We've switched from service account keys to serviceAccountIds (or tried to) so we can clean up all the rouge keys we have. After rolling out the change we're seeing:

Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/xxxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com.; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature....}}

The thing is, we've definitely got the correct role applied (see attachment). We've even tried a few more for good measure.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you try with a different service account? Also make sure the service account, and the Cloud Functions instance belong to the same Firebase/GCP project.

Comment: Hey Hiranya. I've tried a few service accounts to check if it's related to how they're created. Also checked the environment (the service account names are fairly unique so this is easy to validate from the error message). Still no joy.

Comment: That's quite strange. Perhaps you can try calling the IAM REST API directly using one of your service accounts. That will help us rule out if something weird is happening at the SDK level. Beyond that all I can suggest is reaching out to GCP support: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/free_trial_support

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean call the signing endpoint? Can you provide it with just a service account id? I'll give it a try...

Comment: Why roles merged to one service account? In my setup that 3 role associated to 3 different service accounts. Editor role for firebase-admin-sdk, Cloud Functions Service Agent for a robot account (...gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com) and the Service Account Token Creator role associated to a service account which is belonging to the Cloud Function also.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka - so I managed to make a call with the api. The problem is the API uses a service account key to create an oauth token so I'm not sure its a valid test of this scenario? Do you know how the sdk takes just a service account ID and manages to sign a token? I've used the .INTERNAL.getToken to get an OAuth token and made a direct call to :signJwt but I get the same exceptions.

Comment: I open a support ticket and will feedback here if I find a solution.

Comment: @Yan it sounds like the test you did is correct.  You can also try the same against the [signBlob endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob), which is what Firebase SDKs use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two service accounts being used in this case:

1. The service account used to authorize RPC calls (in case of Cloud Functions, this is the App Engine default service account).
2. The service account you have specified as the `serviceAccountId`.

It seems IAM only works when BOTH service accounts have the `signBlob` permission. I have inquired the GCP/IAM team about this. In the meantime, here are couple of fixes you can try immediately:

- Grant the token creator role to the App Engine default service
  account of your project.
- Once you do that, you don't have to
  specify a `serviceAccountId` at all. The SDK will auto-discover that same
  service account ID when running in Functions.

Comment: I'll try this today. I did try this when we initially hit the problem and it didn't work but that might be because it was only on one of the accounts.The API call is somewhat confusing as the service account key is in the URL but the oauth token required can come from a different service account key - I've been debugging the SDK and from what you're saying the oauth token must be from the default service account.

Comment: Can I test this locally? I tried setting the serviceAccountId to be the same as the default account and that didn't work. I also noticed that the token creator role was already applied... after deploying I was able to create a token but as an acid test I removed the token creator from every service account and was still able to create tokens. Any thoughts as to what's actually happening?

Comment: So I tested this some more - you only need signBlob on the GAE default account. You can omit it from the serviceAccountId account. Even more interestingly, if you use the GAE account name for the serviceAccountId it actually uses cert signing and doesn't need either account to have the permission! :)

Comment: Yes, I have also found out that you only need the permission on the service account used to obtain OAuth2 tokens (i.e. the one used as credentials). I don't think there's a way to sign tokens without granting the permission to that service account. That looks like it was caused by the IAM permission cache. I've noticed that permission revocation takes a couple of minutes to take effect in IAM.