# How to get getDownloadURL from onFinalize cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm working on a website where users can upload images. As they upload an image, an `onFinalize` is triggered that will create a document with, among other things, an image URL. Before using cloud functions, I would use `getDownloadURL` on the client side to get imageURL and save it to the doc but since I'm using cloud functions, I'm now using the image metadata and the mediaLink as imageURL but I can see that it's not performing the same as `getDownloadURL`.

This is the function that I'm using at the moment:

```
exports.imageFirestoreCreate = functions.storage
  .bucket()
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    console.log(object);
    if (
      object.contentType.startsWith("image/") &&
      object.name.startsWith("images/")
    ) {
      const uploadDate = object.timeCreated;
      const imageLink = object.mediaLink;

      const images = firestore.collection("images");

      return images.add({
        imageURL: imageLink,
        createdAt: uploadDate,
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to `getDownloadURL` from an onFinalize?

Comment: So you only need to get the downloadUrl of the newly created file?

Comment: @AlexMamo, yes. im lookiing for the URL that i can use to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need a Cloud Function that should be triggered when [a new file is uploaded to the Storage Bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?gen=1st). To be able to read the download URL via Cloud Functions and not the client side, then please use the following lines of code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp()

exports.imageFirestoreCreate = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const newFile = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket).file(object.name);
    const config = { action: 'read', expires: '01-01-2033' };
    const downloadUrls = await newFile.getSignedUrl(config);
    const downloadUrl = downloadUrls[0];
        
    const images = firestore.collection("images");
    await images.add({
      imageURL: downloadUrl,
    });
});
```

The above code will add a new document in the `images` collection that contains the download URL of the uploaded file.

Comment: This solution is giving me an error ```Error: Cannot sign data without "client_email"```. Is this an error that exists because i'm using an emulator or would it appear anyway?

Comment: Yes, most likely it's because of the emulator. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803446/google-cloud-firebase-storage-error-cannot-sign-data-without-client-email) is how you can fix it.