# Get URL from firebase storage file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to get a downloadURL from a file inside my storage from within the *onFinalize* trigger. In a best case scenario, I want an URL as short as possible (so preferably not a signed one, but just one like the public one like it can be seen in the Firebase Storage UI). Keep in mind, that I am moving the file first, so I cannot access it directly from the *onFinalize* parameter.

I currently have the following solution:

```
await imageRef.move(newPath);
const newFile = defaultBucket.file(newPath);
const url = (await newFile.getSignedUrl({
                 action: 'read',
                 expires: '03-09-2491'
}))[0];
```

This approach has two flaws:

- Apparently the signed URL is only valid for 3 days. This may be a [known issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/144)
- The URL is very long and takes much space in my Firestore

I also saw an approach, where the URL is being reproduced from the bucket name and the token, but I did not manage to find the token in the metadata of the file.

Comment: You say you want a URL like the public URL in the UI.  Is that URL acceptable by itself?  If so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072883/get-public-url-from-file-uploaded-with-firebase-admin seems to give you what you need.

Comment: That answer is not dealing with the token which is required to get the URL. The first approach is not working, and the second approach is the one I stated here, where the URL is only valid for some days.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase/43764656#43764656) describes how to get and use the download token. Maybe it's the one you already saw?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. The first problem is, that I don't know how I can access the metadata, since I am copying the file, so I can't pass parameters to the upload process. Also, the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` is not documented in any products, so it may be removed in an upcoming version.

Comment: Why do you call 'move()' and not 'upload()'? You could specify the token [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656). Note that token metadata is nested. And, just to check, have you tried following the steps in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)?