# how to get download URL after uploading an image to Firebase Storage programatically using cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I need to get download URL like this one for the image in my firebase storage:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxxxn.appspot.com/o/profilePicture%2F0JAKUtQYN6wTuAo5D7Xn.jpg?alt=media&token=54143e9d-db25-4b7b-a8b5-1f32c2ab14fd

in iOS, I can get the link using

```
import Firebase

Storage.storage().reference()child(path).downloadURL { (urlStorage, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there is an error while getting downloadURL String firebase storage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil)
        } else {
            print("successfully get downloadURL String firebase storage firebase storage")
            completion(urlStorage?.absoluteString)
        }
    }
```

but at this time I need to get the link in background trigger using cloud function. the code below will be triggered if an image uploaded to Firebase Storage

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const defaultStorage = admin.storage()
admin.initializeApp()

export const updateUserProfileImagePathAfterUploadingImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

      // I don't know what to do in here. I can't access 'child' in 'defaultStorage' to access download URL like in the iOS code


    })
```

Comment: Add this code to your function:  `console.log(object.mediaLink);` Then upload a file and check the logs.  According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata), object should be an ObjectMetadata.

Comment: To get the download URL from server-side code, you call `getSignedUrl()` on the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase