# how to get service-account.json to get signedURL in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I try to follow the answer in here [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase) . to get the download URL for my image stored in Firebase storage

but i need to get service-account.json keyFilename when initializing `gcs` for the code below

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename: 'service-account.json'})
```

I don't know how to set up `{keyFilename: 'service-account.json'}` correctly.but here is what I've done:

1. first, I generate the private key from here and name it as service-account.json https://console.firebase.google.com/project/yourprojectID/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk , the service-account.json contains information like this:

   {
     "type": "service_account",
     "project_id": "",
     "private_key_id": "",
     "private_key": ,
     "client_email": "",
     "client_id": "",
     "auth_uri": "",
     "token_uri": "",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
     "client_x509_cert_url": ""
   }
2. and then place the file in the function folder and use it like the picture below:

[image]

but I get error from cloud function log:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../service-account.json'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../service-account.json' }
```

the `gcs` is actually used to generate thumbnail whenevet I upload an image to the storage using the code from here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what it is you're observing that indicates you haven't set this up correctly. Is there an error message when running the code?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as accepted after enough time passes for SO to allow it.

Comment: Hello Agung. What is the environment of this image? I should put service-account.json inside src folder and the link is here:https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer   I would appreciate if you tell me what I should do. which software? Or what should I do with those files in the link.

Answer (score -1):

newbie mistake, should be `./service-account.json` instead of `../service-account.json`