# Upload synthesized speech from firebase function node.js server's tmp directory

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tmp

I am trying to upload the audio returned by Google's Text-to-Speech API in a Firebase Function and having trouble writing the audio file to the Node.js server's temp directory. I receive the following error in my functions log:

> Write ERROR: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/synthesized/output.mp3' at Error (native) errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT',  syscall: 'open', path: '/tmp/synthesized/output.mp3' }

Here's my imports:

```
    // Cloud Storage
    import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage';
    const gcs = new Storage();

    import { tmpdir } from 'os';
    import { join, dirname } from 'path';
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    import * as fse from 'fs-extra';

    // Cloud Text to Speech
    import * as textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech';
    const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
```

...and the part of my function I'm having trouble with:

```
    // Construct the text-to-speech request
    const request = {
        input: { text: text },
        voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL' },
        audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
    };

    // Creat temp directory
    const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'synthesized');
    const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'output.mp3');

    // Ensure temp directory exists
    await fse.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
    client.synthesizeSpeech(request)
        .then(responses => {
            const response = responses[0];
            // Write the binary audio content to a local file in temp directory
            fs.writeFile(tmpFilePath, response.audioContent, 'binary', writeErr => {
                if (writeErr) {
                    console.error('Write ERROR:', writeErr);
                    return;
                }
                // Upload audio to Firebase Storage
                gcs.bucket(fileBucket).upload(tmpFilePath, {
                    destination: join(bucketDir, pageName)
                })
                    .then(() => { console.log('audio uploaded successfully') })
                    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Synthesize ERROR:', err);
        });
```

What is wrong with my temp directory creation or `fs.writeFile()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer edited in response to question edit...)

In your original question, you invoked

```
client.synthesizeSpeech(request, (err, response) => {...})
```

following Node's `http` callback pattern, in which the callback function may initiate before the response is complete. Your subsequent code calls methods that assume response content; if the response is still empty, `fs.writeFile()` writes nothing initially, and subsequent methods cannot find the non-existent file. (Because `fs.writeFile()` follows the same callback pattern, you might even discover that `output.mp3` file after the program exits, because  `fs` will stream the input. But I bet your Firebase methods aren't waiting.)

The solution is to use Promises or async/await. Looking at the [Google `TextToSpeechClient` class docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/text-to-speech/0.3.x/v1.TextToSpeechClient), it looks like the `synthesizeSpeech` method supports this:

> Returns: Promise -> Array. The first element of the array is an object representing SynthesizeSpeechResponse.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> client.synthesizeSpeech(request)
>   .then(responses => {
>       var response = responses[0];
>       // doThingsWith(response)
>   })
>   .catch(err => {
>       console.error(err);
>   });
> ```

That should solve the problem with `client.synthesizeSpeech`, but unfortunately `fs.writeFile` is still synchronous. If you were using Node >10 you could use a native `fsPromise.writeFile` method, and if you were using Node >8 you could use `util.promisify()` to convert `fs.writeFile` to promises. But you've indicated in comments that you are using Node 6, so we'll have to do things manually. Thieving from [this reference](https://dev.to/mrm8488/from-callbacks-to-fspromises-to-handle-the-file-system-in-nodejs-56p2):

```
const writeFilePromise = (file, data, option) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, option, error => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            resolve("File created! Time for the next step!");
        });
    });
};

client.synthesizeSpeech(request)
    .then(responses => {
        const response = responses[0];
        return writeFilePromise(tmpFilePath, response.audioContent, 'binary');
    })
    .then(() => {
        return gcs.bucket(fileBucket).upload(tmpFilePath, {
            destination: join(bucketDir, pageName)
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('audio uploaded successfully');
        return null;
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
```

I've written all of this using `.then` constructs, but naturally, you could also use `async`/`await` if you would rather do that. I hope this fixes things--it will force your Firebase code to wait until `fs.writeFile` has completed its job. I have also, unfortunately, smooshed all of the error checking into one final `.catch` block. And made things a bit verbose for clarity. I'm sure you can do better.

Comment: Thank you, Andy! I've updated `synthesizeSpeech` to return a Promise. I still have the same error, and am slowly chewing over things to implement your other advice. Two challenges I'm up against: Firebase Functions uses Node.js 6 so fsPromises is not available, and I'm still wrapping my head around Promises and async-await. But I'm getting there, so was excited to hear that my solution lay in implementing those techniques!

Comment: @JacobBowdoin, could you update your question with your new code? I understand what you are saying about still getting the error, and I can think of a number of (Promise-related) reasons why. I can also help you manually promisify for Node 6--just because we can't use fsPromise doesn't mean we can't implement them on our own.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've updated the question with my current code. Thank you for pursuing getting to the bottom of this!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I can see that the nested `gcs.bucket().upload()` function is still not async with respect to `fs.writeFile()`; it's not waiting for writeFile to finish (or even start, really) its job before it fires. We need to manually promisify that method. I'll update my answer with a replacement.

Comment: Updated answer. Alternately, I noticed that Firebase Functions allows for use of Node 8 in beta; this would let you use `util.promisify`.

Comment: Thank you! It works and I took that last .then a step further to grab the audio's downloadURL path (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
     .then(() => {
         console.log('audio uploaded successfully');
         const updloadedAudioFile = gcs.bucket(fileBucket).file(audioName);
         return updloadedAudioFile.getSignedUrl({
              action: 'read',
              expires: '03-09-2491'
         }).then(signedUrls => {
              audioPath = signedUrls[0];
         });
      })

Comment: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises) on how to convert from **Callbacks** to **Promises**. I'm new to Js as an Android Developer so this post was useful. Thanks!