# Including Async Function Within Firebase Cloud Functions (eslint "Parsing error: Unexpected token function")

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

## Issue

How can an `async` helper method be added to a *Cloud Functions'* *index.js* file? An `async` function is required in order to use `await` when converting `fs.writefile` into a **Promise** as explained in this StackOverflow post: [fs.writeFile in a promise, asynchronous-synchronous stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978347/fs-writefile-in-a-promise-asynchronous-synchronous-stuff/53689011#53689011). However, *lint* does not approve of adding an additional method outside of the `exports` functions to the *index.js* file.

## Error

Line **84** refers to the helper function `async function writeFile`.

> Users/adamhurwitz/coinverse/coinverse-cloud-functions/functions/index.js
>     84:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token function
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/adamhurwitz/.npm/_logs/2018-12-12T01_47_50_684Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

## Setup

*index.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const util = require('util');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'project-id',
});
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getAudiocast = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const bucket = storage.bucket('gs://[bucket-name].appspot.com');
  var fileName;
  var tempFile;
  var filePath;

  return client.synthesizeSpeech({
    input: {text: data.text },
    voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
    audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
  })
  .then(responses => {
    var response = responses[0]; 
    fileName = data.id + '.mp3'
    tempFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);  
    return writeFile(tempFile, response.audioContent)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Synthesize Speech Error: " + err);
  })
  .then(() => {
     filePath = "filePath/" + fileName;
     return bucket.upload(tempFile, { destination: filePath })
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.error("Write Temporary Audio File Error: " + err);
  })
  .then(() => {
   return { filePath: filePath }
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.error('Upload Audio to GCS ERROR: ' + err);
  });
});
```

Helper method:

```
async function writeFile(tempFile, audioContent) {
    await fs.writeFile(tempFile, audioContent, 'binary');
}
```

## Attempted Solution

Enabling Node.js **8** as recommended in the post [Cloud Functions for Firebase Async Await style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444273/cloud-functions-for-firebase-async-await-style).

1. [Set Node.js version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version)
   `"engines": {"node": "8"}`
2. `return await fs.writeFile(tempFile, audioContent, 'binary');`

Lint does not like this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Node.js 8 - Promisify

Enabling Node.js **8** as recommended in the post [Cloud Functions for Firebase Async Await style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444273/cloud-functions-for-firebase-async-await-style).

1. [Set Node.js version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version)
   `"engines": {"node": "8"}`
2. Use `promisify`

   `const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);`

   `return writeFile(tempFile, response.audioContent, 'binary')`

## Pre Node.js 8 - Manual Conversion

This is an older approach to convert Callbacks to Promises as outlined by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509361/2253682) regarding a more specific question about Google Text To Speech (*TTS*).

```
const writeFilePromise = (file, data, option) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       fs.writeFile(file, data, option, error => {
          if (error) reject(error);
          resolve("File created! Time for the next step!");
       });
   });
};

return writeFilePromise(tempFile, response.audioContent, 'binary');
```

Comment: "engines": {"node": "8"} was the key for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 156):

I tried all solutions above which did not work for me. It was due to bad syntax in my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
```

changed to :

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
```

Like said Burak in the comments, this dot is put by default when we create firebase functions

Comment: I'm not sure that this solves the problem. From my experience it makes eslint work against the wrong target directory. Try to have bad indentation and it won't be flagged anymore

Comment: BE CAREFUL with this. Maybe I'm missing something, but for me this "fix" turned off lint warnings completely.

Comment: **THIS IS NOT A FIX** It does not make eslint "work" -- it makes eslint *not actually scan your code*. You may as well delete the entire lint script if you're going to do this.

Answer (score 20):

Your eslint is not configured to understand ECMAScript 2017 syntax.  The .eslint.json config file that's created by the Fireabse CLI by default includes this configuration:

```
"parserOptions": {
  // Required for certain syntax usages
  "ecmaVersion": 6
},
```

Change it like this to help it understand async/await:

```
  "ecmaVersion": 2017
```

Comment: I've added `"ecmaVersion": 2017` to the *eslintrc.json* file in the project, however **Lint** is still throwing an error when returning a promise generated from the `await`: `return await fs.writeFile(tempFile, responses[0].audioContent, 'binary');`

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.

Comment: The only difference is replacing the `promisify` with the `await`. Otherwise, the `writeFile` method works as expected when using `promisify` so I can move forward with that approach.

Comment: True, the most recent versions adopt the format as `es2017: true` in the env section

Answer (score 15):

### ISSUE ES7 you have to change it to ES8

- ES7 released on 2016 does not have async,await nor arrow functions
- ES8 released on 2017 have have async,await and arrow functions

you have to check on your .eslintrc that you have at least es8 or 2017 which is the same.

**if the file is  .eslintrc.json**

"ecmaVersion": 2017
or
"ecmaVersion": 8

**if the file is  .eslintrc.js**

env:{
es8:true,
node:true
}

for some it works that way

### **In my case it solved by changing package.json**

"scripts": { "lint": "eslint ." },

changed to :

"scripts": { "lint": "eslint" },

**as Jonathan Said but I wonder why?**

and a realized that I had two files with the name

- .eslintrc.js
- .eslintrc.json

[this is eslintrc.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UYUe.png)

and

[this is eslintrc.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2D6u.png)

as you can see there are diferent versions of ecmaScript in the two files with the same name,

- "ecmaVersion": 2017  // which is equal to es8 in file: .eslintrc.json
- es6: true, // which was released on June 2015 in file: .eslintrc.js

so when we run : **npm run lint** it runs the .eslintrc.js with es6:true
so to solve this conflict was just to **delete  .eslintrc.js** because it has the wrong ecmaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The difference between js and json file has helped. I wish I can double upvote this answer.

Answer (score 14):

**If you have `.eslint.js`** - just change `es6: true` to `es2017: true`.

For example:

```
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
```

becomes:

```
  env: {
    es2017: true,
    node: true,
  },
```

More details in [ESLint language options doc](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments).

Comment: This solved my issue exactly.

Answer (score 0):

change ecmaVersion in .eslintrc.json

> "parserOptions": {
>       // Required for certain syntax usages
>       "ecmaVersion": 8
>     }

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.
I used the same ESLint configuration as used in one of the functions in the Firebase functions samples GitHub repo. I referred to this particular example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/child-count, which makes use of async functions.
I removed the **eslintrc.js** and replaced it with the same **eslintrc.json** file as in the above sample. Also, in **package.json**, added a new dependency     `"eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1"`, and removed the default `"eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0"` (Again, as is in the above sample).

This seems to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

**.eslint.json**

"parserOptions": {
// Required for certain syntax usages
"ecmaVersion": 6
},
Change it like this to help it understand async/await:

"ecmaVersion": 2017

**package.json**
"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint ."
},
changed to :

"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint"
},

**Refereces Captain Web and Doug Stevenson**

Comment: Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.