# What is the purpose behind getDownloadURL of Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Per these [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl()), I understand once we have the firebase path in storage, we can get the download url by calling `getDownloadUrl()` on this path's `ref`. My question is all the docs suggest to get the download url first then download file data based on these image, but can we persist this download url in our realtime db for the file, so we don't have to call `getDownloadUrl()` each time?

***Current file upload and download workflow ->***

**Upload:**

```
 1. upload file to storage in specific path.
 2. store path in realtime DB to persist for future downloading purposes
```

**Download**

```
 1. get object from realtime DB and retrieve storage path
 2. get storage object
 3. get url from getDownloadUrl() on that object
 4. download data from url
```

***Better upload/download workflow ->***

**Upload:**

```
 1. upload file to storage in specific path.
 2. get download url from storage object 
 3. store download path in realtime DB to persist for future downloading purposes
```

**Download**

```
 1. get object from realtime DB 
 2. get download url stored in object
 3. download data from download url
```

What is `getDownloadUrl()` doing under the hood and is the given url static?

Comment: I believe the issue is the actual download URL might change, dynamically.  So no, you shouldn't persist it.  Just call `getDownloadUrl()` each time, per the documentation.

Comment: That would make sense. Is this primarily because firebase determines the closest CDN to the client and serves it from there?

Answer (score 3):

The download URL is meant to be persisted.  It's a waste of time for clients to call it every time.  This is illustrated consistently in Firebase sample code.

Comment: The question also asks about what's going on under the hood and if the URL is static, and that's exactly what I was wondering but couldn't find completely in the docs. It seems like one benefit of the download URL is that it could be revoked. However, while I have some hunches, I don't think it's obvious why you need the download URL. Can you explain why a client can't just request the path directly from Google Cloud Storage? It also seems like once you have the download URL, permissions go "out the door" and the URL is effectively public so any user with the URL can see a file. Is that right?

Comment: Along similar lines, should one _always_ persist the value? If the URL gives anybody access to read a file, what about a case where you have a document in the database that has a related image in storage, but the doc is shared with users of 2 different roles. 1 role is allowed to see the image, but the other is only allowed to see the metadata. In that scenario, if you want a single doc for efficiency and cost, would you want to persist only the path in the database so that permissions on seeing the image would be determined at the storage level per user when they call `getDownloadURL`?