# Firebase storage getDownloadURL creates infinite loop

Tags: vuejs2, firebase-storage, infinite-loop, nuxt.js

When trying to retrieve the URL from an uploaded file from firebase storage I get an infinite loop which locks my browser.

HTML

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item, idx) in data" :key="item.id">
  <img :src="get_image_url(item.id, item.images)">
</div>
```

VueJS functions
Get images

```
get_image_url: function(id, images) {
  storage.ref().child('products/' + id + '/' + images[0]).getDownloadURL()
  .then(url => {
    console.log(url)
    return url
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Get data

```
created: function() {
  db.collection('shops').doc(vm.$route.params.id)
  .collection('inventory').get()
  .then(res => {
    res.forEach(doc => {
      const id = doc.id
      const data = doc.data()
      vm.data.push({ id, ...data })
    })
  })
}
```

[image: infinite loop]

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue, but the error message doesn't look related to the code you've shown

Comment: Can you please add what is data, how you get and store it.

Comment: I was able to get it working by getting the image while downloading the data directly (see update).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you get the url of the image while getting the data it will not cause an infinite loop.

HTML

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item, idx) in data" :key="item.id">
  <img :src="item.url">
</div>
```

Vue Created

```
created: function() {
  db.collection('shops').doc(vm.$route.params.id)
  .collection('inventory').get()
  .then(res => {
    res.forEach(doc => {
    storage.ref().child('products/' + doc.id + '/' + doc.data().images[0]).getDownloadURL()
    .then(resp => {
      const id = doc.id
      const data = doc.data()
      const url = resp
      vm.data.push({ id, resp, ...data })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I ran into this too when doing something similar in Vue. However, I've found that it seems like the URL is meant to be persisted according to the Firebase team in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055190/what-is-the-purpose-behind-getdownloadurl-of-firebase-storage. "It's a waste of time for clients to call [`getDownloadURL()`] every time."