# How to use bucket.upload() instead of file.createWriteStream() in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get the permanent (unsigned) download URL after uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage. I can get the signed download URL using `file.createWriteStream()` but `file.createWriteStream()` doesn't return the `UploadResponse` that includes the unsigned download URL. `bucket.upload()` includes the `UploadResponse`, and [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase) has several answers explaining how to get the unsigned download URL from the `UploadResponse`. How do I change `file.createWriteStream()` in my code to `bucket.upload()`? Here's my code:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({ projectId: 'my-app' });
const bucket = storage.bucket('my-app.appspot.com');
var file = bucket.file('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + wordFileType);

const config = {
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025',
  content_type: 'audio/mp3'
};

function oedPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(oedAudioURL, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options))
        .on('error', function(error) {
          console.error(error);
          reject(error);
        })
        .on('finish', function() {
          file.getSignedUrl(config, function(err, url) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              return;
            } else {
              resolve(url);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I tried this, it didn't work:

```js
  function oedPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      http.get(oedAudioURL, function(response) {
        bucket.upload(response, options)
        .then(function(uploadResponse) {
          console.log('Then do something with UploadResponse.');
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      });
    });
  }
```

The error message was `Path must be a string.` In other words, `response` is a variable but needs to be a string.

Comment: with your existing get.writestream could you just use FS as input to the cloud storage put(file)?  http to localfilesys  -> cloudStorageRef.put(getFile(file))  its extra io but seems to conform to what various functions expect/ result in .

Comment: What exactly is `config` that you're passing to `getSignedUrl`?  Is it whatever getSignedUrl accepts as a first argument?

Comment: Doug, I've edited my question to include `config`. It's copied from the `getSignedUrl` documentation, including the strange `expires` date that implies that signed URLs work for more than seven days.

Comment: Robert, that's a good question. Google Cloud Storage uses `file` instead of `fs` because it doesn't have a local file system. The documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/. Looking at other documentation, I see: "You can use the Google Cloud Storage FUSE tool to mount a Cloud Storage bucket to your Compute Engine instance. The mounted bucket behaves similarly to a persistent disk even though Cloud Storage buckets are object storage." https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets

Comment: Could I use the FUSE tool with `file.createWriteStream()` to save the file to a location that `bucket.upload()` can recognize as a string? That seems like overkill. If `bucket.upload` is a wrapper around `file.createWriteStream`, how does `bucket.upload()` have an `uploadResponse` but `file.createWriteStream` doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

I used the [Google Cloud text-to-speech API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/text-to-speech) to simulate what you are doing. Getting the text to create the audio file from a text file. Once the file was created, I used the [upload](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) method to add it to my bucket and the [makePublic](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#makePublic) method to got its public URL. Also I used the [async/await feature](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/) offered by node.js instead of function chaining (using then) to avoid the 'No such object: ..." error produced because the makePublic method is executed before the file finishes uploading to the bucket.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
// Creates a client using Application Default Credentials
const storage = new Storage();
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
// Get the bucket
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my_bucket');

// Import other required libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

// Create a client
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
    
// Create the variable to save the text to create the audio file
var text = "";

// Function that reads my_text.txt file (which contains the text that will be
// used to create my_audio.mp3) and saves its content in a variable.
function readFile() {
    // This line opens the file as a readable stream
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/home/usr/my_text.txt');

    // Read and display the file data on console
    readStream.on('data', function (data) {
        text = data.toString();
    });

    // Execute the createAndUploadFile() fuction until the whole file is read
    readStream.on('end', function (data) {
        createAndUploadFile();
    });
}

// Function that uploads the file to the bucket and generates it public URL.
async function createAndUploadFile() {
    // Construct the request
    const request = {
        input: {text: text},
        // Select the language and SSML voice gender (optional)
        voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
        // select the type of audio encoding
        audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
    };

    // Performs the text-to-speech request
    const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    // Write the binary audio content to a local file
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile('my_audio.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
    console.log('Audio content written to file: my_audio.mp3');

    // Wait for the myBucket.upload() function to complete before moving on to the
    // next line to execute it
    let res = await myBucket.upload('/home/usr/my_audio.mp3');
    // If there is an error, it is printed
    if (res.err) { 
        console.log('error'); 
    }
    // If not, the makePublic() fuction is executed
    else { 
        // Get the file in the bucket
        let file = myBucket.file('my_audio.mp3');
        file.makePublic(); 
    }
}


readFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

`bucket.upload()` is a convenience wrapper around `file.createWriteStream()` that takes a local filesystem path and upload the file into the bucket as an object:

```js
bucket.upload("path/to/local/file.ext", options)
  .then(() => {
    // upload has completed
  });
```

To generate a signed URL, you'll need to get a file object from the bucket:

```js
const theFile = bucket.file('file_name');
```

The file name will either be that of your local file, or if you specified an alternate remote name `options.destination` for the file on GCS.

Then, use `File.getSignedUrl()` to get a signed URL:

```js
bucket.upload("path/to/local/file.ext", options)
  .then(() => {
    const theFile = bucket.file('file.ext');
    return theFile.getSignedURL(signedUrlOptions); // getSignedURL returns a Promise
  })
  .then((signedUrl) => {
    // do something with the signedURL
  });
```

See:

`Bucket.upload()` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/Bucket#upload)

`File.getSignedUrl()` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/File#getSignedUrl)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't want the signed download URL because signed download URLs expire in seven days. I want the permanent, unsigned download URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a specific file in a bucket publicly readable with the method [makePublic](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File#makePublic).

From the docs:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

// 'my-bucket' is your bucket's name
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

// 'my-file' is the path to your file inside your bucket
const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.makePublic(function(err, apiResponse) {});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.makePublic().then(function(data) {
  const apiResponse = data[0];
});
```

Now the URI `http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]` is a public link to the file, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data).

The point is that you only need this minimal code to make an object public, for instance with a Cloud Function. Then you already know how the public link is and can use it directly in your app.

Comment: `file.makePublic()` produces an error, "No such object:` and my bucket_name/object_name. This is one promise after `file.createWriteStream()`, so `file` hasn't changed. I'm not sure how it can't find the object it just made. I also tried `predefinedAcl: 'authenticatedRead'` and `predefinedAcl: 'publicRead'`, these produce `403 (Forbidden)` errors. I'm not getting `404 (Not Found)` errors so the URI appears to be good.

Comment: Can you check if your file and bucket object references are ok? It looks like you pass an url to storage.bucket(), is it the bucket name? I suggest you try to see if the minimal example code, with minimal changes, works for you.

Comment: I just opened a new question with these problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957920/google-cloud-storage-predefinedacl-and-file-makepublic-not-working