# Google Cloud Storage `predefinedAcl` and `file.makePublic()` not working

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get permanent download URLs when I upload files to Firebase Storage (Google Cloud Storage) from Firebase Cloud Functions (Google Cloud Functions).

I tried setting `predefinedAcl` to `authenticatedRead` and to `publicRead`. Both resulted in `403 (Forbidden)` errors when my app tried to download the files. This is from the documentation for [CreateWriteStreamOptions](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/global#CreateWriteStreamOptions). Here's the code:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({ projectId: 'languagetwo-cd94d' });
const myBucket = storage.bucket('languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com');

var mp3Promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let options = {
        metadata: {
          contentType: 'audio/mp3',
          public: true
        }
      };

      synthesizeParams.accept = 'audio/mp3';
      var file = myBucket.file('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + word + '.mp3');
      textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams)
      .then(function(audio) {
        audio.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options));
      })
      .then(function() {
        resolve('http://storage.googleapis.com/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + word + '.mp3');
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
```

That code executes without an error, writes the file to Storage, and passes the download URL to the next function. When I try to download the file with this URL:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio/English/United_States-Allison-Female-IBM/catbirds.mp3
```

I get this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio/English/United_States-Allison-Female-IBM/catbirds.mp3.
</Details>
</Error>
```

Downloading the file from my app (as an authorized user) I get the `403 (Forbidden)` error message.

I've also tried this property, with the same result:

```js
let options = {
        metadata: {
          contentType: 'audio/webm',
          predefinedAcl: 'publicRead'
        }
      };
```

Moving on, I tried `file.makePublic()`:

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({ projectId: 'languagetwo-cd94d' });
const myBucket = storage.bucket('languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com');

var mp3Promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let options = {
        metadata: {
          contentType: 'audio/mp3'
        }
      };

      synthesizeParams.accept = 'audio/mp3';
      var file = myBucket.file('Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + word + '.mp3');
      textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams)
      .then(function(audio) {
        audio.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options));
      })
      .then(function() {
        file.makePublic()
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          resolve('http://storage.googleapis.com/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio/' + longLanguage + '/' + pronunciation + '/' + word + '.mp3');
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
```

This code didn't even execute. It crashed at `file.makePublic()` and the error message was

```
{ Error: No such object: languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio/English/United_States-Allison-Female-IBM/warblers.mp3
```

I'm not sure what this error means. My guess is that `file.createWriteStream()` wrote to a file location, and then `file.makePublic()` couldn't find that file location.

I found the permissions for `warblers.mp3` on the Cloud Storage Browser:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the first error is due the access permissions to the bucket, in the link you can 
find Identity and [Access Management (IAM)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) instructions, there you can check the roles 
and permission to manage the bucket access.

The second error could be a consequence of the first one.

Please let me know if the information works for you.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation has a lot of information. I have my Firebase Storage Rules set for authenticated users to read everything:  `allow read: if request.auth != null;`. The documentation seems to say that setting `predefinedAcl: 'authenticatedRead'` when uploading an object will do for a file what I set for the entire database, i.e., there's no reason for me to set this property on uploads. I'm getting the `403` error from an authenticated login so that's not what's causing the error. I don't know why `makePublic()` doesn't work it would likely result in the same error.

Comment: I tried changing my Firebase Storage Rules to public read `allow: read;` and I'm getting the same error message, `Access denied. Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access...` This suggests that `makePublic()` wouldn't make these download URLs work, the problem isn't that the files aren't public.

Comment: Hi Thomas, well this issue seems to be related to the bucket's permissions, you need to declare as public the objects or files into the bucket, to do this you can follow the steps in the link[1], there is describe the way you can make an object public a how to get the URL to share it.                                                                              [1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

Comment: Interesting that the menu on Google Cloud differs then from the one on Firebase. Which one is the golden source of truth? Trying the steps about I simply get an error entitled "IAM policy update failed" "Backend error" upon attempting to save the allUser / reader role. Feels flaky as hell

Answer (score 1):

You need to change options to this:

```
let options = {
    public: true,
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'audio/mp3'           
    }
};
```

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#CreateWriteStreamOptions

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue for a while and in the end here is what solved it for me:

```js
const stream = file.createWriteStream(options)
audio.pipe(stream)
stream.on('finish', () => {
  // file APIs will now work
})
```

The problem is that `audio.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options))` creates a stream that writes to the file asyncronously. At the moment when you are calling `file.makePublic()` there is no guarantee that that write stream has completed.