# Facing issue with signedUrl using @google-cloud/storage in firebase-cloud-functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I want to create signedUrl of an image(saved in firebase-storage) out of its path, as we know, firebase sdk doesn't provide such functionality in firebase-cloud-functions, so i've followed the instructions given at [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

I'm able to generate the url for image via cloud-function, but after opening that link in browser, receiving the following error.

```
   <Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code> 
   <Message>Your request has a malformed header.</Message> 
   <ParameterName>signature</ParameterName> 
   <Details>Signature was not base64 encoded</Details>
```

Comment: Unlikely this is your problem - but I realised I was getting exactly this error because I was 'ctrl+clicking' the link in the VS code terminal - and it was only copying a partial URL into chrome. If I manually copy and paste the full URL into chrome, it was actually valid.

Comment: @dsg38 haha heck yeah man this just fixed me up :D

Comment: @dsg38 This should be an answer. Fixed it for me too!

Comment: @AndreasTzionis - Just added as an answer. Up vote would be appreciated :)

Comment: @JosephMckenzie  - Just added as an answer. Up vote would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely this is your problem - but I realised I was getting exactly this error because I was 'ctrl+clicking' the link in the VS code terminal - and it was only copying a partial URL into chrome. If I manually copy and paste the full URL into chrome, it was actually valid.