# Signed URL is working beyond expiration date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a signed URL with 2 days expiration and despite expiration it is working. I want it to give some error 3XX, 4XX

[test script ] 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/forvaidya/984003008b0603ca679a3fe556b478db/raw/f7dc7a14868eb4d37ac6648108d910e728602c67/test.sh

Comment: Hi.. You got exactly opposite problem to mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304431/url-from-getsignedurl-will-expire-in-few-weeks . It looks like setting expiration date doesn't do any difference

Comment: Can you share the method you used to generate the signedUrl?

Comment: Try to follow the steps I have provided in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304431/url-from-getsignedurl-will-expire-in-few-weeks I believe this will also help your case