# Signed Url is working after the expiration date Cloud Storage python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504545/signed-url-is-working-beyond-expiration-date) that seems dead so i will add more context.

i am using the python google-cloud-storage sdk to generate signed urls using `blob.generated_signed_url()`.

Here is the full method i use :

```
blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1), version="v4")
```

I live in France so my Timezone is +1h from datetime.now().

The generated URL looks fine, i see the part of the expiration and the date : `X-Goog-Date=20230318T191451Z&X-Goog-Expires=3659`

But now it's 20min after this delay and the doc is still available.

Note : I have also tried using `timedelta(hours=1, minutes=1)` to simulate the France Timezone but it is still available also after 2mins of waiting.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls),

> `X-Goog-Expires`: The length of time the signed URL remained valid, measured in seconds from the value in `X-Goog-Date`.

In your case, it's `3659` that's roughly an hour and not a minute. Try:

```
url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
    method="GET",
)
```

This should work irrespective of your timezone as it's using a `timedelta` instance so `timedelta(hours=1, minutes=1)` would be *61 minutes*. Timezone should be concern if you are using `datetime` instance instead as mentioned in the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_generate_signed_url):

> If a datetime instance is passed without an explicit tzinfo set, it will be assumed to be UTC.