# What is the difference between mediaLink and SignedUrl in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a firebase function to upload files to firebase storage, after upload I have to return the url (as Reset response) so that user can view the file

```js
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const [file, meta] = await bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
            destination: uploadPath,
            resumable: false,
            public: true,
        });
```

I have two options

1- `const signedUrl = await file.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-09-2491' });`

2- `meta.mediaLink`

SignedUrl will be like `https://storage.googleapis.com/web-scanner-dev.appspot.com/pwc%2Fwww.x.com%2F2019-11-17%2Fdesktop%2Fscreenshot-2019-11-17-1125.png?GoogleAccessId=firebase-gcloud%40scanner-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=16447035600&Signature=w49DJpGU9%2BnT7nlpCiJRgfAc98x4i2I%2FiP5UjQipZQGweXmTCl9n%2FnGWmPivkYHJNvkC7Ilgxfxc558%2F%2BuWWJ2pflsDY9HJ%2Bnm6TbwCrsmoVH56nuGZHJ7ggp9c3jSiGmQj3lOvxXfwMHXcWBtvcBaVj%2BH2H8uhxOtJoJOXj%2BOq3EC7XH8hamLY8dUbUkTRtaWPB9mlLUZ78soZ1mwI%2FY8DqLFwb75iob4zwwnDZe16yNnr4nApMDS7BYPxh4cAPSiokq30hPR8RUSNTn2GxpRom5ZiiI8dV4w%2BxYZ0DvdJxn%2FW83kqnjx6RSdZ%2B9S3P9yuND3qieAQ%3D%3D`

and mediaLink will be like `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/web-scanner-dev.appspot.com/o/pwc%2Fwww.x.com%2F2019-11-17%2Fdesktop%2Fscreenshot-2019-11-17-1125.png?generation=1574007908157173&alt=media`

What is the pros and cons of each?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mediaLink` does not convey any access permissions on its own -- thus, the object itself will need to be [publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) in order for end uers to make use of the link (or you will need to be authenticated as an account with read access to that bucket when you execute the link).

On the other hand, a URL returned by `getSignedUrl` will have a signature that [allows access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers) for as long as the URL hasn't expired.  Thus, the link alone is sufficient (if temporary) permission to access the blob.  Additionally, the URL that is generated maintains the permissions of the user who created it -- if that user loses access to the blob before the link would otherwise expire, the link will no longer function.