# Inserting record in Firebase DB from Storage

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I need to store some images inside Firebase Storage and I was wondering if there's any way to add a record inside Realtime DB with the download url when adding an image inside Storage.

I don't want to do it necessarily from an app, is there a way to add a record to DB just by adding an image inside Storage from the console?

I was trying to retrieve the images urls directly from Storage but in some cases it resulted tedious and I thought that putting the urls inside the DB would be easier. And it was a good opportunity to try Realtime DB too.

Comment: You can always copy the URL from Firebase storage console and paste in RTDB but that'll be manual process. What are you looking for? or you can use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and use a cloud function to update database once image is uploaded

Comment: Do you need to do that programmatically or manually? If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @Dharmaraj i want it to be automatic, i'll take a look on the triggers, i think that could be the answer

Comment: @AlexMamo i want it to be automatic and i'm more experienced in JS :)

Comment: And you need to code for that?

Comment: @AlexMamo well yes, i'm working on a project for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) for Cloud Functions that'll add the URL in database after a file is uploaded like this:

```js
exports.updateDb = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  // read object data
  // add required data to Firebase RTDB
});
```

You cannot get the Firebase storage download URLs with the `?token=` parameter using Admin SDK so also checkout [How can I generate access token to file uploaded to firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432624/how-can-i-generate-access-token-to-file-uploaded-to-firebase-storage).

If you don't want to use Cloud Functions then you can simply fetch the download URL, and then update database directly from client SDK.