# Why do I not have access to my firebase storage images?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have two image files uploaded to firebase storage:

[image]

capsule house.jpg was uploaded through the UI (clicking the Upload file button).

upload_64e8fd... was uploading from my backend server (node.js) using this:

```
const bucket = fbAdmin.storage().bucket('gs://assertivesolutions2.appspot.com');
const result = await bucket.upload(files.image.path);
```

capsule house.jps is recognized as a jpeg and a link to it is supplied in the right hand margin. If I click on it, I see my image in a new tab. You can see for yourself:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/assertivesolutions2.appspot.com/o/capsule%20house.jpg?alt=media&token=f5e0ccc4-7916-4245-b813-dbdf1838556f

upload_64e8fd... is not recognized as any kind of image file and no link it provided.

The result returned on the backend is a huge json object with the following fields:

```
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/assertivesolutions2.appspot.com/o/upload_64e8fd09f787acfe2728ae73158e20ab"
"mediaLink": "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/assertivesolutions2.appspot.com/o/upload_64e8fd09f787acfe2728ae73158e20ab?generation=1590547279565389&alt=media"
```

The first one sends me to a page that says this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The second one gives me something similar:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

The rules for my storage bucket are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm allowing all reads and writes.

So why does it say I don't have access to see my image when it's uploaded through my backend server?

I'd also like to know why it doesn't recognize it as a jpeg when it's uploaded through my backend server, but it does when uploaded through the UI, but I'd like to focus on the access issue for this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Only the client-side for Firebase (iOS, Android, Web) generate download URLs that allow public access to the file. When you upload a file through the Node.js client, no such download URL is generated, and the file is by default not accessible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: Thanks to both you Frank and gso_gabriel for your links. It's a lot to read through and I'll get back to this thread when I get through it. Just wanted to say thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the files are uploaded as private, unless you change your bucket settings, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage/issues/20). The below code is an example of how to change the visibility of your documents.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setVisibility($path, $visibility)
{
    $object = $this->getObject($path);

    if ($visibility === AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PRIVATE) {
        $object->acl()->delete('allUsers');
    } elseif ($visibility === AdapterInterface::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) {
        $object->acl()->add('allUsers', Acl::ROLE_READER);
    }

    $normalised = $this->normaliseObject($object);
    $normalised['visibility'] = $visibility;

    return $normalised;
}
```

You can check how to set that via console, following the tutorial in the official documentation: [Making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)

Besides that, as indicated in the comment by @FrankvanPuffelen, you won't have a generated URL for the file to be accessed. You can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks to both you gso_gabriel and Frank for your links. It's a lot to read through and I'll get back to this thread when I get through it. Just wanted to say thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think bringing up generated URL is confusing. After the ACL makes the file public, the standard URL `http://BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com/OBJECT_NAME` works anonymously for me.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer helped me! I have no idea why the Console had me make those security rules if they won't apply...

Based on [nodejs docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) (and probably other languages) there is a simple way to make the file public during upload:

```js
const result = await bucket.upload(files.image.path, {public: true});
```

This same option works for `bucket.file().save()` and similar APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow public read access

```
public String uploadImage(String name, String image) {
    final byte[] bytes = Util.convertBase64ToByteArray(image);
    final String imageExtension = Util.getImageExtensionFromBase64(image);
    final String img = name+"."+imageExtension;

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    final BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, img);
    final BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
            .setContentType("image/"+imageExtension)
            .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(List.of(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER)))) // allow read access
            .build();
      
    final Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, bytes);
    return blob.getMediaLink();
}
```