# Generate expiring download link for newly purchased item

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am building a simple static website selling a single pdf file using the Stripe checkout api.

I would like to be able to generate an expiring download link after the customer successfully purchased the pdf.

I am really not sure about how to do this, but I was thinking about using firebase to store the file in a bucket and somehow use a cloud function to generate a temporary download link that expires after some time, but I am not sure how to go about this (or if this is even the best solution).

Can anyone give me some help about which direction to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase'd download URLs don't expire, although you can revoke the from the Firebase console.

But a better fit for your use-case might be to use Cloud Storage's signed URLs, which have a built-in expiration attribute. You can generate these with the Cloud Storage SDKs or Firebase's Admin SDKs, all of which should only be run in trusted environments - such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

Also see:

- [A guide to Firebase Storage download URLs and tokens](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens).
- [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)