# How to get long term persistent download link from firebase storage using onfinalize trigger in java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm writing an OnFinalize trigger for Firebase storage when the image is uploaded, we have to capture the long-term persistent download link and need to store it into the Firestore collection.

How to get the long-term persistent download link from Firebase storage. I can see samples using nodejs, javascript, and android but I've particularly required a code snippet on pure java source code.
The expected download url is **https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.appspot.com/o/{folder-1}/{folder-2}/{folder-3}/A5.jpg?alt=media&token={image-access-token}**

Comment: While the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656/209103) may be written in JavaScript, it should be fairly straightforward to port to Java, especially when you also keep these docs handy: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-java. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Have tried the below code, getting nullpointerexception, getting blob object as null. ````Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId({PROJECT_ID}).build().getService();
  Blob blob = storage.get({BUCKET_NAME}, {BLOB_NAME},
    Storage.BlobGetOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.values()));````