# How to upload file to firebase storage through API and make it readable to all authanticated users?

Tags: r, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to upload audio files to firebase storage using gcs_upload function in googleCloudStorageR R package. These files need to be accessed by everybody authenticated through firebase authentication.

If I go to Firebase Storage Console and upload the files manually, it automatically creates an access token and generate a link to access the file, under the file name (see image below).

When I upload through googleCloudStorageR, it does not generate the access token, neither the link to access the file.

1. How to upload it (not manually) in a way that anyone authenticated may access it?
2. How to change (through an API other than the console) the access control for the uploaded files?
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the Firebase client-side SDKs, and the Firebase console, provide the option to generate so-called download URLs. This option does not exist in most server-side SDKs, or the REST APIs.

Your two alternatives are to either generate a long-lived signed URL for your upload (which most server-side SDKs do support), or to explicitly set an access token in the metadata of the file as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656. The code sample there is for Node.js, but the approach works across all SDKs that allow you to set custom metadata.