# Avoid re-generating token when using Firebase Image Resize Extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am using [Firebase resize extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images) successfully to generate thumbnails while deleting the original picture but once the extension is triggered, the original static token is re-newed for the new resized picture. In order to read the thumbnail I need to run a new `ref.getDownloadURL()` which I would really like to avoid (extra complication + extra cost). Is there a way to tell the extension (or the underneath function) to keep the old token (metadata) ? Most answers on s.o. seems to refer to older version of the extension or solve a partially similar issue but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the code of the Image Resize Extension function as [suggested by Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896106/2408863):

1. Enable The Image Resize Extension as per usual
2. Go to your Cloud function tab, click on the `ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage` and from the 3 dots on the right select `Detailed Usage Stats`
3. This will bring you to [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/europe-west1/ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID)
4. From here browse to the [lib/resize-image.js](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/9f8d7fd6048bcaa7b5bc505cebe2e90494359e33/storage-resize-images/functions/lib/resize-image.js#L110-L112) file and remove lines 110..112 or add a comment for the whole line 111
5. Save and re-deploy the cloud function
6. Enjoy your resized images with the old UUID

Answer (score 1):

Since a new file is written by the extension, there is no built-in way to keep the old token. It was an explicit decision to not reuse the existing token, so you might want to read up on that [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/323).

What you *can* do is to set the old token in the `metadata/metadata/firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` property yourself as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656). The Extension pretty much does the same [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/9f8d7fd6048bcaa7b5bc505cebe2e90494359e33/storage-resize-images/functions/lib/resize-image.js#L110-L112), but it always generates a new token. If you want to keep the old token, you will have to do this in code, or modify the extension yourself.