# How to get firebase generated download url on Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded image using Firebase sdk on Flutter, on Flutter side i can usually just call getDownloadUrl() on the reference, then i want to get that url on my Cloud Function trigger so if image is uploaded on Firebase Storage i would get the download URL and post it on firestore.

I have tried getting metadata mediaLink but it is not the same url which i can found manually from browsing firebase storage console.

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const filePath = object.name;
    const contentType = object.contentType; 
    const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    
    const jobId = fileName.replace("poster_","").replace(".png","");
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const file = bucket.file(filePath);
    const posterMetadata = await file.getMetadata();
    const posterFileUrl = posterMetadata[0].mediaLink;
    return functions.logger.log('url: '+posterFileUrl );
}
```

Using that url i got "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object." error,

How to get this generated link, which we can found on firebase storage console

[image]

Comment: You can either [generate a signed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959262) (which is the Google Cloud Storage concept for publicly accessible URLs for files) or [add a token to the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656) (which then gets you a Firebase download URL). I linked he question with both answers, which is the first link I get when I [put your title in search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+firebase+generated+download+url+on+Firebase+function).

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want, in a Cloud Function triggered when a new file is uploaded to Cloud Storage, to get the signed URL of this file.

The following will do the trick:

```
exports.generateFileURL = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {

    try {
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
        const file = bucket.file(object.name);

        const signedURLconfig = { action: 'read', expires: '01-01-2030' };

        const signedURLArray = await file.getSignedUrl(signedURLconfig);
        const url = signedURLArray[0];

        // Do whatever you want with the signed URL
        // e.g. save it to Firestore

        await admin.firestore().collection('signedURLs').add({ fileName: object.name, signedURL: url })
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }

});
```

We use the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method from the Cloud Storage Node.js Client API. You'll find in the documentation more details on the possible properties and values of the configuration object passed to the method (i.e. `signedURLconfig` in the above example).

Comment: thanks for answering, but as far as i know the signedUrl generated would only valid for few weeks using this method and i need a long lived one,  
is there a way to just fetch the generated url on firebase since i uploaded it via firebase client wont it like saved on metadata or something?

Comment: "Is there a way to just fetch the generated url on firebase since i uploaded it via firebase client" => Why don't you use the **client** Flutterfire [`getDownloadURL()` method](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls) and save it to Firestore (from the client)? You cloud try adding this URL to the object's metadata, I've never tried.

Comment: at first i do use getDownloadUrl on client side, but then i face problem when using generate thumbnail trigger on cloud function, since sometime the generate thumbnail function is executed before the firestore document created , so i tried to created the firestore document first then uploading the image to make sure it executed when document created

Comment: The probem is that you cannot use `getDownloadUrl()` if the object doesn't exist. What you could do is to trigger the make thumbnail Cloud Function on the Firestore doc creation, not on the file creation.

Comment: I see thats a good workaround i will try, thanks for helping