# How to get downloadURL of uploaded file in firebase storage on Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-storage

In Java Spring boot, I can get the signed url using firebase-admin sdk.

```
Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket();
Storage storage = bucket.getStorage();
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucket.getName(), storeFileName)
                .setContentType(fileType).build();
URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 5, TimeUnit.DAYS, Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
                String signedPath = url.toString();
```

But I need to get the downloadUrl instead of signed url in the Java Spring Boot like the following flutter code.

```
// Flutter Code
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(storePath);
String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
```

I can't add the Firebase-Storage sdk in Java Spring, Only Mobile possible.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-storage/11.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admin SDKs for Cloud Storage are pretty thin wrappers around the GCP libraries for those platforms, which indeed don't provide a `getDownloadURL` method.

The closest equivalent that the GCP SDKs have is a so-called [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which is similar to a download URL, but has an expiration timestamp.

If that doesn't meet your needs, you can set a metadata property on the file to generate a download URL yourself as shown in this answer: [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656).