# Get url of uploaded file in firebase storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading a file to firebase bucket with this code

```
 const uplaodTask = await storage.bucket('example.appspot.com').upload('/temp/out.png', {
   destination: `/${jobID}/results/${filterName}.png`,
});
```

How can I get the public url of the uploaded file? I tried the following code but it's not working

```
 uplaodTask.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-09-2491'
}).then(signedUrls => {
  console.log("URL: ", signedUrls[0])
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42956250/13130697) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)