# How to get Link of an Image that is uploaded using Raspberry pi in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, cloud

Hey I already have Uploaded **image** using **Raspberry pi** in **Firebase Storage**, I may want to know how can I generate image url from Raspberry pi and send that generated url to **firebase real-time database**.

Although my question is not realted to any error, but I would really appreciate I someone can help me to achieve this.

There is a manual way in firebase storage that is to click on image and copy paste URL from image to realtime database but I want this functionality to be done from Raspberry pi end.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the approaches are enumerated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010225/209103. The approach setting `metadata: { firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid }` will give you a download URL.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it in Python?

Comment: The approach can be applied in any supported language, including Python. I recommend giving it a try, and reporting back with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.