# Firebase storage with Golang - how to upload file and obtain download url with token

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a FE application written in Rescript which handles uploading files to our Firebase storage in GCP and returns a download URL. The URL contains a token  (without expiration date) which allows anyone that has the link to download the file. The code goes something like this:

```
let storageRef = Firebase.Storage.makeRef(storage, `${id}/${filename}`)
Firebase.Storage.getDownloadURL(storageRef)->Promise.then(url =>...)
```

The result URL is something like:

```
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{my-bucket}/o/{object-path}?alt=media&token={some-token}
```

Now I'm writing a golang script to migrate some files into our storage. I figured out how to upload the file and obtain a download URL but it's very different from the URL that rescript code is obtaining.
My code looks like this:

```
config := &firebase.Config{
    StorageBucket: myBucketName,
}
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), config, option.WithCredentialsFile(myServiceAccountKeyFileName))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}

client, err := app.Storage(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing storage client: %v\n", err)
}

file, err := os.Open(myFilePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v\n", err)
}
defer file.Close()

ctx := context.Background()

bucket, err := client.DefaultBucket()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error getting default bucket: %v\n", err)
}

object := bucket.Object(myFilePath)
writer := object.NewWriter(ctx)

if _, err := io.Copy(writer, file); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error uploading file: %v\n", err)
}

if err := writer.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error closing writer: %v\n", err)
}

fmt.Println("File uploaded successfully")

downloadURL, err := bucket.SignedURL(object.ObjectName(), &storage.SignedURLOptions{
    Expires: time.Now().AddDate(100, 0, 0),
    Method:  "GET",
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error getting download URL: %v\n", err)
}
```

But the download URL is in a completely different form:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/{my-bucket-name}/{filename}?Expires={timestamp}&GoogleAccessId={my-service-account}&Signature={long-signature}
```

while the URL is working and allows me to download the file, it has completely different structure from the one above.
How do I make the Go code to upload the files and retrieve a download URL in the same format as from Rescript code?

Answer (score 0):

That first URL is a so-called download URL as generated by the Firebase SDKs to provide public, read-only access to a file.

The second URL is a so-called signed URL as generated by the Google Cloud SDKs to provide public read and/or write access to a file.

There is no way to generate a download URL from the Google Cloud SDKs, but there is a trick that allows you to generate such a URL yourself by setting the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` metadata on the file. For an example of this, see these answers to: [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

- [All known methods of getting a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010225/209103)
- [Just the download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764656/209103), which is probably what you want

Comment: The thread you linked suggest that the firebaseStorageDownloadTokens is no longer supported and was never documented... So there is no way to get the URL other than using javascript SDK?

Comment: As far as I know, setting the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` still works. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` today and it still works. Just that I can't find it anywhere in the Firebase Storage library.

Comment: This feels more like a work-around than a solution. @FrankvanPuffelen. Is there a way to GetDownloadUrl as there is in the javascript SDK? I have also found issues with `bucket.SignedURL` as well as `*storage.Writer.Attrs().MediaLink`. The latter working for emulators, but returning 401 responses in production.

Comment: There is currently no method to get a (non-expiring) download URL on the Go lang SDK. I just answered as much on the question you posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097449/how-to-getdownloadurl-with-go-firebase-admin-sdk/78097695#78097695