Is there support for getting the download URL of a file uploaded to firebase storage using Go admin sdk?
I'm using the package firebase.google.com/go/v4 and trying to upload a file to firebase storage and have a download link to use the file later in other apps. The documentation especially for Go is quite vague. I'm wondering if there's even a method like getDownloadURL() as in the admin sdk for node.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097449/how-to-getdownloadurl-with-go-firebase-admin-sdk

You can infer the download link yourself by passing a custom token to the admin SDK upload.

The Firebase Admin SDK is just a thin wrapper around the an underlying Google Cloud Platform SDK when using Cloud Storage. It exposes generally the same APIs, so the GCP documentation is relevant for use with Firebase Admin.
The GCP SDKs don't have a concept of "donwload URL" like the Firebase client libraries have.  The most similar concept is signed URLs, which you can read about in the GCS documentation and API documentation.
If this doesn't meet your needs, and you require something closer to Firebase's download URLs, you should file a request on GitHub for that.
